# Does this line in a log mean that I have a bad RAM sector or chip?

Tags: logs, ram

```
Aug  4 15:11:09 LiquidNZXT kernel: [    0.000000] *BAD*gran_size: 64K   chunk_size: 32M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -16M
```

Does this line in a log mean I have a bad RAM sector or chip?

Comment: Have you tried running a RAM test?

Comment: @Crash Could you post output of the command: `journalctl -k -b` somewhere at https://pastebin.ubuntu.com

Comment: Please calm down; I cleared all the comments that don't have anything to do with the actual question. I don't know where you got the impression that you can't answer comments like "have you tried running a RAM test", but you can and it'd be a good start to diagnosing the problem

Answer (score 8):

Six years ago I had similar problem with my Fedora server. The kernel messages:

```
*BAD*gran_size...
```

can have three basic reasons:

- corrupted physical memory
- corrupted BIOS
- wrong MTRR size

I have solved the problem by enabling MTRR sanitizer, [read my post](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?283340-Multiple-*BAD*gran_size-messages&p=1598336#post1598336) (I'm `melal` on Fedora forum) and [another post](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?283340-Multiple-*BAD*gran_size-messages&p=1609319#post1609319) below it.

Additionally read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190904223631/http://my-fuzzy-logic.de/blog/index.php?/archives/41-Solving-linux-MTRR-problems.html), to understand what the messages `*BAD*gran_size...` mean.